# Class with pointers to variadic template template parameters

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, variadic-templates

Can someone give me some insight into why this code doesn't work:

```
template <template <class... Ts> class Derived>
struct Base
{
   Base(Derived<Ts...>* d_param) : d(d_param) {}

   Derived<Ts...>* d;
};
```

I'm using GCC 4.8.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that a template template parameter may have identifiers for the template's parameters, but they are unusable. Depending on your envisioned use, you need either to pass in the complete type or a template and its parameters separately. Examples for the first option:

```
template< class Derived >
struct Base
{
    Base(Derived* d_param) : d(d_param) {}
    Derived* d;
};
```

used as

```
Base< std::map< int, double > > x;
```

or if you need to have separate parameters your second option is:

```
template< template<class...> class Derived, class... Ts >
struct Base
{
    Base(Derived<Ts...>* d_param) : d(d_param) {}
    Derived<Ts...>* d;
};
```

used as

```
Base< std::map, int, double > x;
```

Comment: That second one is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!